# How can i open a link in safari when i click UIWebView?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, safari

I'm trying to open one link in safari when i click the UIWebview (its  like ad display).
Following code am using but  what happend is when i click the webview its opening inside UIWebview for some links (not all).

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView1 shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{


    if (webView1==webview) {

        if (UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked == navigationType) {

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
            return NO;
        }

        return YES;

    }
}
```

**what happens here is if any  text link in that UIWebView then its opening correctly ,But if a UIWebview with images then its opening in same UIWebview instead of a new browser.**

**MY CURRENT CODE**

```
     - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/files/ad.htm"]]];
    [_webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [_webView setOpaque:NO];
    _webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;


    }

-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

[image: when i load the app i can see the ad]

[image: When i click on that ad(UIWebview) it opens in same UIWebview instead of a browser]

Comment: so the html file that ur loading in webview is local?

Comment: @iOSCoder yes   actually one url is there if its no working then it will load from local file

Comment: @Popeye Is there any way to open safari by clicking uiwebview

Comment: why this if conition "if (webView1==webview) "?

Comment: what does this means ? its opening inside UIWebview for some links (not all).

Comment: @Popeye opening inside uiwebview

Comment: @iOSCoder lots of webview s are there,so if i click webview(for ad) then it will open in new browser

Comment: http://blog.spritebandits.com/2012/07/17/q8-uiwebview-links-in-safari/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like those images has been linked using anchor tags...

Try this...

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    static NSString *reguler_exp = @"^(([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])[.])+([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$";
//Regular expression to detect those certain tags..You can play with this regular expression based on your requirement..

    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", reguler_exp];
//predicate the matched tags.

    if ([resultPredicate evaluateWithObject:request.URL.host]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
        return NO; 
    } else {
        return YES; 
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Don't allow this delegate method to get called for the first time.Add some logic that it won't get called for the 1st time loading the webview.

(**SOP's new requirement,see below comment**)

How to to detect the touch on uiwebview,

1)Add the tapgesture to your webview.(before that add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in your viewcontroller.h)

example:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* singleTap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired=1;
singleTap.delegate=self;
[webview addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

2)Then add this delegate method,

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    //return YES,if you want to control the action natively;
    //return NO,in case your javascript does the rest.
}
```

**Note**: In case you want to check whether the touch is native or htmml(javascript) check the nice little tutorial [**here**](http://pkcoder.blogspot.in/2012/12/feel-difference-between-html-touch-and.html),about handling the javascript events etc....Hope this helps you..

Comment: is there any methdoe for knowing webview is clicked or not?

Comment: its up to you..what ur need is..thats done by apple engineers,so its not a bad :-)

Comment: @Please check my updated question..that code is crashing for me

Comment: My mistake its not crashing but its not opeing the browser ..but i can see That NSLog(@"tap"); i sprinting

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35991/discussion-between-ioscoder-and-navi)